# .htaccess redirect all URLs with paths to one place, but URL without path to another place

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Hopefully someone can help me. I'm attempting to do the following:

If a user navigates to blog.example.com (with no path), I would like the user redirected to www.example.com/blog.

However, if the user navigates to blog.example.com/blog-post-name, I would like to redirect the user to www.example.com/blog-post-name.

I've attempted various rules within .htaccess but I haven't had any luck. Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.example.com$
RewriteRule ^$     http://www.example.com/blog [L,QSA,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://www.example.com/$1   [L,QSA,R=301]
```